# Lazy loaded collection empty in junit

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, junit, spring-data-jpa

I have an SpringBoot application in which I have defined an entity as given below

```
@Entity
public class Organisation {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@JsonIgnore
private Long id;

private String entityId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
@Where(clause = "active_ind=true")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Organisation> activeSubOrgs = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
private Organisation parent;

public Set<Organisation> getActiveSubOrgs() {
    return activeSubOrgs;
}
```

In my service class I have a function to fetch the children

```
public Set<Organisation> getChildrenForEntity(String entityId) {
    Organisation parent = organisationRepository.findByEntityIdAndActiveInd(entityId, true);
    return parent.getActiveSubOrgs();
}
```

This works fine and gets the children when called from rest controller, but when I use the same function to test in junit, it always returns empty. In my sql trace log I see that query is not being triggred when getActiveSubOrgs() is being called. My junit test is as given below

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Transactional
public class OrgServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private OrganisationService organisationService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Organisation company = new Organisation("c", true);
        company = organisationRepository.save(company);
        Organisation circle = new Organisation("circle1", true);
        circle.setParent(company);
        circle = organisationRepository.save(circle);
        Organisation div1 = new Organisation("div1", true);
        div1.setParent(circle);
        div1 = organisationRepository.save(div1);
    }

    @Test
    public void getChildrenForEntitySuccessTest() {
        Set<Organisation> children = organisationService.getChildrenForEntity("c");
        System.out.println(children.iterator().next().getEntityId());
        assertEquals("circle1", children.iterator().next().getEntityId());
    }
```

The children Set in the test is empty when it should actually have circle1. I have tried calling Hibernate.initialize() on children, but that did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that bidirectional relationships have to be updated on both sides, i.e. the parent and the children have to know about each other. In your function `setup()`, you just define the parent of the child. Therefore, each child knows about its parent. However, the parent does not know about its children.

For bidirectional relationships, a good way of handling this is to define a function for one class to set/add a property and automatically update the other one. In case of `OneToMany` relationships, this can be handled nicely with `add(entity)` functions.

```
public void addActiveSubOrg(Organisation activeSubOrg) {
    this.activeSubOrgs.add(activeSubOrgs);
    activeSubOrg.setParent(activeSubOrg);
}
```

Comment: Yep. Updating bidirectionally works. But tell me this, I have a service that sets the parent in a similar manner without adding to children of parent. Why does it make proper entries in the db, but does not update the java side objects?

Comment: The Java objects can be in a detached state, i.e. they do not reflect the current database. I am not sure what in your implementation actually happens. Anyway, keep bidirectional entities always synchronised to avoid exceptions. You can read about the different statuses within Hibernate [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-hibernate-entity-state-transitions/).